# Как найти максимальное значение среди столбцов в Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, index

Код должен перебрать значения столбцов строки и вернуть индексы(в идеале сразу имена) тех столбцов, значения в которых максимальны. Вот функция которую я написал:

```
data = pd.read_csv(path)

def max_val_ind(data):
  c=0
  final_idx = pandas.Series()

  for i in range(0,len(data.index)):

    max_val=0;
    max_ind=pandas.Series();
    samp = data.iloc[i,idx[c]]

    if samp>max_val:
      max_val=samp
      max_ind.append(c)
    elif samp==max_val:
      max_ind.append(c)
    final_idx.append(max_ind)
    c+=1

  return final_idx

max_val_ind(data)
```

Про задачу: значения столбцов рейтинг - игрока на позиции на позиции, моя задача - найти оптимальную(-ые) позиции для каждого игрока и записать их в отдельный столбец

ГитХаб с датасетом  https://github.com/georgemartynov/fifa_data

Пример:
На входе получаем вот такую таблицу:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
На выходе хочу увидеть столбец, где будут записаны названия столбцов с максимальным значением в строке

best_positions:

ls,rs

ls

st

rb

cb,lb

rwb,rb,rcb,cb

Comment: Как должен выглядеть результат? Если вы не приводите пример того, что хотите получить в результате, то тем, ктот пытается вам помочь приходится угадывать. В случае если мы не угадали - мы вам не помогли и потратили впустую наше и ваше время.

Comment: На будущее: приводите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных и то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: `где будут записаны названия столбцов с максимальным значением в строке` - название или названия? Если названия, то как это должно выглядеть? Как CSV (comma separated values)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas
import seaborn as sns
#загружаем данные
data = pandas.read_csv('players_20.csv')
#меняем сумму в столбцах на значение
col_idx = (data.columns == "ls").argmax()
data.iloc[:, col_idx:] = data.iloc[:, col_idx:].fillna('0+0')
r = (data.iloc[:, col_idx:].dropna().apply(lambda x: x.str.split("+", expand=True).rename(columns={0:"a", 1:"b"}).astype(int).eval("a+b")))
data.iloc[:, col_idx:] = r
#ищем столбцы с максимальным значением и записываем их
best = [r.columns[i].tolist() for i in r.values == r.max(axis=1)[:,None]]
data['best_pos'] = best
```

Comment: хорошее решение! +1

Answer (score 3):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [DataFrame.max(axis=1)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) или [DataFrame.idxmax(axis=1)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) если вы хотите получить имя столбца с максимальным значением для каждой строки.

Comment: спасибо за ответ! Но вопрос скорее заключался в том, чтобы получить именно названия и как сделать так, чтобы их могло быть несколько, а не одно. Возможно это моя вина, что я некорректно сформулировал вопрос.